# Unable to validate a button

Tags: javascript

If i press a submit button,it goes to another jsp page.
But before going that submit button function has to validate if another button was already clicked.

how to do. below is not working

```
function validatecart()
    {

        if(document.getElementById('cartid').clicked == false)
        {
            bootbox.alert("Please add item to cart by clicking above button"); 

        }
        else
            {
            return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: How is `validatecart()` called? Are you setting an element with `onclick="validatecart()`?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working?"  are you seeing an error?

Comment: I dont think you can use clicked. You have to attach an event listener to cartid, and when it's clicked set a variable to true. The on submit you check the variable if it's true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 var clicked = false;
 document.getElemenstByTagName('button').onclick = function() {
  clicked = true;
  }​;​
 document.getElemenstById('cartidButton').onclick = function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     (!clicked)
     ? bootbox.alert("Please add item to cart by clicking above button"); 
     :return true;
   }
```